Comunicate to a k3s cluster from other docker container on the same network
I have a golang test that setup multiple stand alone docker containers using dockertest lib, and a k8s cluster that I setup using k3s.
As part of the test, I'm creating a docker network with name "my-docker-network". I need the docker containers to be able to access the k8s cluster, how can I do that?
For example:
func setup(ctx context.Context, pool *dockertest.Pool, network *dockertest.Network) error {
    resource, err := pool.RunWithOptions(&dockertest.RunOptions{
        Name:       myContainerName,
        Repository: "my-container-repo",
        Tag:        "my-tag",
        Networks:   []*dockertest.Network{network},
    })
    if err != nil {
        // ....
    }

    k3sContainer, err := k3s.Run(ctx, "docker.io/rancher/k3s:v1.27.1-k3s1",
        network.WithNetwork([]string{}, &testcontainers.DockerNetwork{Name: network.Network.Name}),
        testcontainers.WithConfigModifier(func(config *container.Config) {
            config.Cmd = []string{
                "server",
                "--disable=traefik",
                "--tls-san=host.docker.internal",
            }
        }))
    if err != nil {
        // ....
    }
    
    // ...
}

In the docker container, I have this code:

    decodedCert, err := b64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(clusterCa)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    k8sConf := &rest.Config{
        Host:            clusterEndpoint,
        BearerToken:     accessToken,
        TLSClientConfig: rest.TLSClientConfig{CAData: decodedCert},
    }
    k8sClient, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(k8sConf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)

    }

    _, err = k8sClient.Discovery().RESTClient().Get().AbsPath("/healthz").DoRaw(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to get k8s /healthz", err)
    }

Which return error:
 Failed to get k8s /healthzGet "https://localhost:62034/healthz": dial tcp connect: connection refused
Everything work as expected when I try this code in localhost, so it's not issue with the certificate or token, I'm also able to make it work by calling https://host.docker.internal:62034/healthz, however it's not working in a github runner ("dial tcp: lookup host.docker.internal on 127.0.0.150:53: no such host").
I wonder how I can setup k3s in a way that I will be able to call it from other docker containers in the same network using https://my-k3s-container:{EXPOSED_PORT}, like I'm doing with the docker containers- I'm able to comminucate between two containers by using the conatiner name I'm passing in dockertest.RunOptions

Instead of trying to launch a completely new Kubernetes cluster, can you use something like the sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/envtest library to make a temporary control plane available?  Also see Configuring envtest for integration tests in the Kubebuilder operator library documentation.  I'd avoid trying to mix Docker and Kubernetes setups at the same time, and for unit tests try to abstract away the Kubernetes API calls to have pure unit tests.
